# Usage of Java generics when the type is known only at runtime

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code:

```
public class Generics {
    C c; // initialized at runtime

    public void testGenericsCall(Object o) {
        c.myMethod(o);
    }
}

class C<E> {
    public void myMethod(E input) {
    }
}
```

This is working, but I get warnings because the parametrized class C is used with a raw type. I cannot use a declaration like

```
C<String> c;
```

because the type of C is known only at runtime. I also cannot add a type parameter to the class Generics because I need to create objects of this class before knowing the type of C. The declaration

```
C<?> c;
```

or

```
C<? extends Object> c;
```

would be OK for the compiler, but then the method testGenericsCall does not compile (*"actual argument java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? by method invocation conversion"*)

What is the best way to deal with a situation like this?

**EDIT**: Note that when I actually (at runtime) create an instance of C, I know its type parameter, this part of the code is type-safe and working well. In the real code, I don't have a single "C" class, but a series of interrelated classes, and there the generics are definitely useful (even if in this simplified example this is not obvious - so please don't just tell me not to use generics :). I already have the compile-time type-safety, but not here, but between C and other classes (not shown here).

I see how in this case I cannot check the type parameter at compile time, that's why I tried to declare it  `C<?> c`. Here **I am just looking for the best way to bridge the generic and not-generic code without compiler warnings.**

Comment: Generics in java will only trigger compile-time checks, so if the type of your generics is unknown until runtime, it's probably best not to use generics at all - you won't get any additional type safety at runtime anyway.

Comment: @Grim: it makes sense to use generics in the C class, because when I create an instance of C, I know its type. The problem is in the Generics class.

Comment: @user1954847 `Simple rule`: If it is impossible to anything about the type of an object at compile time, then it is impossible to implement type-aware code with java generics. It doesn't matter if you know anything about types when you create an object at runtime. After code has been compiled, no traces of generics are left, so generics cannot be used for runtime type checking.

Comment: @Alderath: I understand type erasure, and I see how in this case I cannot check the type parameter at compile time, that's why I tried `C<?> c`. I am looking for the best way to avoid compiler warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Because of [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), there's no way to use generics at runtime. You'll have to deal with your data type programmatically, by checking type or anything (reflection maybe).

Comment: When I create an instance of C, I know its type, therefore I think that using generics gives me a lot of safety in dealing with C (and a series of related classes not mentioned in the question). The question is how can I bridge this "type-aware" code with the "type-unaware" code.

Comment: @user1954847 Doesn't matter if you know the type when you instantiate the object. Anytime you are dealing with run-time types, Generics are **not** a tool you can use. They are purely a compile-time construct.

Comment: @pap I understand type erasure, and I see how in this case I cannot check the type parameter at compile time, that's why I tried C<?> c. I am looking for the best way to avoid compiler warnings. In the real code, I don't have a single "C" class, but a series of interrelated classes, and there the generics are definitely useful.

Comment: Did you try `C<? extends Object>`

Comment: @pap In other words, I do already have the compile-time type-safety, but not here, but between C and other classes (not shown here). Here I just want to bridge the generic and not-generic code without compiler warnings.

Comment: @pap As far as I know, `C<? extends Object>` is the same as `C<?>`, and indeed it results in the same compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. But through dirty tricks and reflection. Look at below code for example. Courtesy [here](http://code.google.com/p/dirty-mockito/source/browse/tags/dirty-mockito-0.4/src/main/java/dirty/mockito/ParameterizedTest.java):

```
class ParameterizedTest<T> {

/**
 * @return the type parameter to our generic base class
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
protected final Class<T> determineTypeParameter() {
    Class<?> specificClass = this.getClass();
    Type genericSuperclass = specificClass.getGenericSuperclass();
    while (!(genericSuperclass instanceof ParameterizedType) && specificClass != ParameterizedTest.class) {
        specificClass = specificClass.getSuperclass();
        genericSuperclass = specificClass.getGenericSuperclass();
    }
    final ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) genericSuperclass;

    final Type firstTypeParameter = parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    return (Class<T>) firstTypeParameter;
}



}

//change the type of PrameterizedTest<Integer> to Parameterized<String> or something to    display different output
public class Test extends ParameterizedTest<Integer>{
 public static void main(String... args){
    Test test = new Test();
    System.out.println(test.determineTypeParameter());
}
```

}

Here on the runtime, you get the Type Parameter. So instead in your class, you will have to define a `Class` object which gets the class as explained above. Then using `Class.newInstance` you get a new Object. But you will have to manually handle type cast and so on.

> The question is: Is all this worth it??

No according to me as most of it can be avoided by using bounds in generic types and interfacing to the bound type

Comment: This is really smart code, but unfortunately it does not answer my question (probably my fault, because everybody seems to misunderstand it, but I cannot formulate better...). I know the type parameter and the object creation works fine. I just would like to get rid of warnings - preferably without @SuppressWarnings annotations... Anyway +1 because I learned something :)

Comment: On reading more above, I get the crux. You can try 2 things: 1) All those types that you think are contenders at run time, make them implement an Interface say `MyType`. And then use `C<MyInit>` in your code. This is possible because you exactly know what actions those types can do for you.

Comment: Secondly what you can do is that:

Comment: The first does not work, because then I would not able to assign to the variable, just like an `ArrayList<Integer>` cannot be assigned to an `ArrayList<Number>`. Your second suggestion is not very clear :)